# Differenza tra camino e ciminiera

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice, difference, single-words

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere qual è la differenza tra un camino e una ciminiera. La seconda parola mi ricorda la parola inglese "chimney", ma la mia impressione è che una ciminiera sia più grande di un camino, magari come la parte di una fabbrica dove esce il fumo, anche se ho sentito il termine ciminiera riferito anche alla parte dove esce il fumo da un camino di casa sopra il tetto.

Grazie.

Comment: Jimmi, prima di fare una domanda così semplice, ci si aspetta che tu faccia un po' di ricerca per conto tuo. Hai letto le definizioni su un dizionario (per esempio, [camino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/camino1/) e [ciminiera](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ciminiera))? C'è qualcosa che non ti è chiaro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **ciminièra** s. f. [dal fr. *cheminée*, che è il lat. tardo *caminata*, der. di *caminus* «focolare»; cfr. [*camminata*²](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/camminata2/)]. – Camino, fumaiolo, spec. quello delle locomotive a vapore, delle fabbriche e, impropriam., delle navi.
>
> (Fonte: [*Vocabolario Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ciminiera/))

Come puoi vedere *ciminiera* è molto vicina a *camino* come significato, anche se è solitamente usata per fabbriche e locomotive. Incidentalmente, sia l'italiano *ciminiera* che l'inglese *chimney* sono derivati dall'antico francese *cheminée* (il cui significato originario sembra essere quello di "[stanza] con camino"), a sua volta derivato dal latino *caminus* che è la forma originale di *camino*:

> **chimney**: Middle English (denoting a fireplace or furnace): from Old French cheminee ‘chimney, fireplace’, from late Latin caminata, perhaps from camera caminata ‘room with a fireplace’, from Latin caminus ‘forge, furnace’, from Greek kaminos ‘oven’.
>
> (Fonte: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chimney))